# How to find the numeric position of the substring with an offset?

Tags: php

if i want to check for an occurance of a string in some text i can use,

`strpos($some_string,"word");` this return first char position of the string.

but what if i want to search for the occurance of a string between a set starting point and end point in the text.

so if the `$text  = "hello my name is fred blogs and i live in a house"`

so `strpos($text,"fred");` would give about 18

what if i had `$text = "hello my name is fred blogs and i live have a brother fred as well and a granda called fred as well"`

now i know that the 2nd "fred" in this string lies between positions A & B so do you `strpos` between these two positions?

Comment: Have you checked [strpos](http://php.net/strpos) manual - and `offset` param in particular?

Comment: As a sidenote, what has `mysql` to do with this question? And why it's given the most generic name possible?

Comment: Regexp with a negative look ahead in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strpos()` takes offset as a third argument so you can do:

```
strpos($text, "fred", 16);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you know the position of point A and B than you can make use of

```
strpos(substr($text,POINT A POSITION,POINT B POSITION),"fred");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 3rd paramater, the offset, to start further in the string. To make it more dynamic:

```
$string = "fred";
strpos($text, $string, strpos($text, $string)+strlen($string));
```

This will find the next occurence after the first found.
I use the `strpos()+strlen()` nested as 3rd parameter to make it start with an offset